# Unable to get the Parent Custom Taxonomy Terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I am unable to get the Parent Taxonomy Terms here is the code i am writing

```
$myterms = get_terms( 'iqvis_event_category', array( 'parent' => 0 ) );
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($myterms);
echo '</pre>';
```

What is the Reason is there any Syntax problem ? or the parent argument is not working?? because if i am not giving the parent argument its working and getting all the terms with their children.

Comment: i don't see any problem with it. there's no syntax problem. include your results

Comment: its nothing all i have to do add another argument `'hide_empty' => 0` then it was returning everything

Comment: @PhpSeeker if that solved your problem, add it as an answer

Comment: Added Already Joseph :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I just have to add another argument and then it was working fine:

```
$myterms = get_terms( 'iqvis_event_category', array( 'parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0 ) );
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($myterms);
echo '</pre>';
```